# blueimp fileupload done not called when uploading files at the same time in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, blueimp

I have a blueimp file upload that has add, done, and progress callbacks. I show the progress of the file upload after selecting a file (I know it doesn't work in IE9 and below but that's fine.) When the file has finished uploading, the file is displayed on a list.

In Chrome and Firefox, I can upload another file while the previous one is still uploading. The files uploaded are added to the list. In IE9 however, only the first file is added to the list and the other files are left in progress. The add is called and the server-side code is hit x number of times though, which means the files were uploaded. How come "done" is hit only once in IE9 when I try to upload files simultaneously?

Here's the sample HTML code:

```
<form action="Upload/UploadFiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="attachments" multiple="multiple" />
</form>
```

and the jQuery:

```
var     fileUpload = $('.file-upload'),
        form = fileUpload.closest('form'),
        fuTrigger = $('<span class="file-upload-trigger">Attach File</span>');

fileUpload.wrap('<div class="file-upload-container">');

var fuContainer = fileUpload.closest('.file-upload-container');
fuContainer.append(fuTrigger);

fileUpload.fileupload({
    maxChunkSize: 1000000000,
    add: function (e, data) {
        var filesContainer = $('.files-container');
        if (!(filesContainer.length > 0)) {
            filesContainer = $('<ul class="files-container"></ul>');
            filesContainer.insertAfter(form);
        }

        //add the progress bar
        var progressBarContainer = $('<li class="progress-bar-container"></li>'),
            progressBar = $('<div class="progress-bar"></div>'),
            loading = $('<span class="loading"></span>'),
            progressLabel = $('<span class="file-name-label"></span>'),
            fileName = data.files[0].name;

        progressLabel.text(fileName);
        progressBarContainer.append(loading).append(progressBar).append(progressLabel);
        filesContainer.append(progressBarContainer);

        var jqXHR = data.submit();

        //add a cancel upload button
        var btnCancelUpload = $('<button class="btn-cancel-upload"></button>');
        btnCancelUpload.text('Cancel').click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            jqXHR.abort();
            progressBarContainer.remove();
        });
        progressBarContainer.append(btnCancelUpload);
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
        var fileName = data.files[0].name,
            progressBarContainer = $('.file-name-label:contains(' + fileName + ')').closest('.progress-bar-container'),
            fileLabelContainer = $('<li></li>'),
            fileLabel = $('<label></label>'),
            fileLabelTextbox = $('<input type="text" class="txt-file-label" />'),
            btnDeleteFile = $('<button class="btn-delete-file"></button>');

        fileLabel.text('File Label').appendTo(fileLabelContainer);
        fileLabelContainer.append(fileLabelTextbox).append('<span class="uploaded-file-name">' + fileName + '</span>').append(btnDeleteFile);
        fileLabelContainer.insertAfter(progressBarContainer);

        progressBarContainer.remove();

        alert('boo!');
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {
        //make progress
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Blueimp' fileupload use IframeTransport on old browser like IE9.

I found in [the FAQ](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions):

> However, the Iframe Transport requires that all selections have to be uploaded in one request, simply because the file input is used for a standard HTML form submit to a hidden iframe and it's not possible to separate the selected files this way.

So I think it's explain your problem : one request implies only one *done* callback.

To verify it you can test it on Chrome or Firefox with the **forceIframeTransport** option.